# Culture specific DateTime string is inconsistent between platforms

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo, currentculture

I have a test application that allows the user to select a culture from a ComboBox and displays the culture specific date in a multiline TextBox. The code is below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(
            CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures));
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo selectedCulture = comboBox1.SelectedItem as CultureInfo;
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

        textBox1.Text =
            "My Date : " + currentDate.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
            "Culture Specific Date: " + currentDate.ToString(selectedCulture);
    }
}
```

I notice that if "ar-SA", Arabic (Saudi Arabia), is selected, then I see different results when I run the application on different machines.

On a Windows 7 machine, the text box displays:

```
My Date : 4/11/2012 4:07:09 PM
Culture Specific Date: 19/05/33 04:07:09 م
```

On a Windows XP machine, the text box displays:

```
My Date : 4/11/2012 4:07:09 PM
Culture Specific Date: 20/05/33 04:07:09 م
```

As you can see, the culture specific date is off by a day. What could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: Is the clock on both systems correct?

Comment: Maybe the sysdate date in the machine is off by a day? What happens when you choose other culture, like `US`?

Comment: The system date is correct. I output "My Date", which is the same on both machines.

Comment: Does the [workaround here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/calendar-and-datetimepicker/valid-values-are-between-1318-and-1450-inclusive-parameter-name-year.aspx) work?

Comment: @Anurag Ranjhan: Thanks, but I don't believe that workaround applies to my situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *suspect* this is due to the Windows XP machine not receiving up-to-date [adjustments to the Umm al-Qura calendar](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/islam/ummalqura_converter.htm#adjust), whereas presumably the Windows 7 box is kept up to date, although I wouldn't *expect* those adjustments to affect the current month. Alternatively, it could be due to this:

> Only recently has more information become available which now makes it possible to reconstruct the calendar adopted on the Arabian Peninsula in the recent past and to predict its future course for many years in advance.

... so maybe the Windows XP implementation is out of date.

(That page agrees that it's currently the 19th, by the way.)