# Culture specific DateTime string is inconsistent between platforms (2)

Tags: .net, datetime, currentculture

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113239/culture-specific-datetime-string-is-inconsistent-between-platforms), hence the title.

Date output is different on the server even though the cultures are the same. Both dev machine and server has the same datae format set in Windows; English (United States). I have modified the the date format for ShortDateString to 'yyyy-MM-dd'. This change only take effect on the dev machine, the server is still displays values in original en-US format.

On the dev machine all i have to do is restart IIS to pick up any changes in date format. The server however is very reluctant and stubborn.

Here is some output from both machines:

On my windows 7 dev machine:

```
Current Culture: en-US
Current UI Culture: sv-SE

Short date format: yyyy-MM-dd
Long date format: 'den 'd MMMM yyyy
UI short date format: yyyy-MM-dd
UI long date format: 'den 'd MMMM yyyy

Decimal number: 1234.5
DateTime.Now: 2013-02-21 19:08:47
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() : 2013-02-21
```

On the Windows 2008 R2 server:

```
Current Culture: en-US
Current UI Culture: sv-SE

Short date format: yyyy-MM-dd
Long date format: 'den 'd MMMM yyyy
UI short date format: yyyy-MM-dd
UI long date format: 'den 'd MMMM yyyy

Decimal number: 1234.5
DateTime.Now: 2/21/2013 7:08:49 PM
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() : 2/21/2013
```

All settings under Region and Language are identical. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Updated the question with more info

Comment: What application/code is producing the strings?  Applications can override machine settings.

Comment: Could it be different browser settings?

Comment: It can't be browser settings.I'm using the same browser for both platforms.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because on your server IIS runs on an other account (not your own), and the will ignore your local setting...
could explain the problem?